# Dynamic routes with Express.js -- is this even possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Every time I update the database with a new menu item, I'm trying to get the routing to update with one more route.  Here's my sad little ugly attempt:

Here in app.js, I check the menu database and shazaam...routes are made on the fly *at startup*.  Cool!:

```
// in app.js //
var attachDB = function(req, res, next) {
    req.contentdb = db.content;
    req.menudb = db.menu;
    req.app = app;  // this is the express() app itself
    req.page = PageController;
    next();
};
db.menu.find({}, function (err, menuitems){ 
    for(var i=0; record = menuitems[i]; i++) {
        var menuitem = record.menuitem;
        app.all('/' + menuitem, attachDB, function(req, res, next) {
            console.log('req from app all route: ',req)
            PageController.run(menuitem, req, res, next);
        }); 
    }

    http.createServer(app).listen(config.port, function() {
        console.log(
            '\nExpress server listening on port ' + config.port
        );
    });
});
```

Not real elegant but it's a proof of concept.  Now here's the problem:  *When I save a new menu item in my Admin.js file, the database get's updated, the router seems to get updated but something about the request just blows up after clicking on a menu link with a dynamically created route*

Many things in the request seem to be missing and I feel like there is something fundamental I don't understand about routing, callbacks or perhaps this is just the wrong solution.  Here's what the function responsible for creating a new menu item and creating a new route in my Admin.js file looks like:

```
// in Admin.js //
menuItem: function(req, res, callback) {
    var returnMenuForm = function() {
        res.render('admin-menuitem', {}, function(err, html) {
            callback(html);
        });
    };
    var reqMenudb = req.menudb,
        reqContentdb = req.contentdb,
        reqApp = req.app,
        reqPage = req.page;

    if(req.body && req.body.menuitemsubmitted && req.body.menuitemsubmitted === 'yes') {
        var data = { menuitem: req.body.menuitem };
        menuModel.insert( data, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Whoa there...',err.message);
                returnMenuForm();
            } else {
                // data is inserted....great. PROBLEM...the routes have not been updated!!!  Attempt that mimics what I do in app.js here...
                reqApp.all('/' + data.menuitem, function(req, res, next) {
                     // the 2 db references below are set with the right values here
                    req.contentdb = reqContentdb;
                    req.menudb = reqMenudb;
                    next();
                }, function(req, res, next) {
                    reqPage.run(data.menuitem, req, res, next);
                });

                returnMenuForm();
            }
        });
    } else {
        returnMenuForm();
    }
},
```

Saving the data in the admin section works fine.  If you console log app.routes, it even shows a new route which is pretty cool.  However after refreshing the page and clicking the link where the new route should be working, I get an undefined error.

The admin passes data to my Page controller:

```
// in PageController.js //
module.exports = BaseController.extend({ 
    name: "Page",
    content: null,
    run: function(type, req, res, next) {
        model.setDB(req.contentdb);  /* <-- problem here, req.contentdb is undefined which causes me problems when talking to the Page model */
        var self = this;
        this.getContent(type, function() {
            var v = new View(res, 'inner');
            self.navMenu(req, res, function(navMenuMarkup){
                self.content.menunav = navMenuMarkup;
                v.render(self.content);
            });
        });
    },
    getContent: function(type, callback) {
        var self = this;
        this.content = {}
        model.getlist(function(records) {
            if(records.length > 0) {
                self.content = records[0];
            }
            callback();
        }, { type: type });
    }
```

Lastly, the point of error is here in the model

```
// in Model.js //
module.exports = function() {

    return {
        setDB: function(db) {
            this.db = db;
        },
        getlist: function(callback, query) {
            this.db.find(query || {}, function (err, doc) { callback(doc) });
        },
```

And here at last, the 'this' in the *getlist* method above is undefined and causes the page to bomb out.

If I restart the server, everything works again due to my dynamic loader in app.js.  But isn't there some way to reload the routes after a database is updated??  My technique here does not work and it's ugly to be passing the main app over to a controller as I'm doing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest two changes:

1. Move this menu attachment thing to a separate module.
2. While you're at it, do some caching.

Proof of concept menu db function, made async with setTimeout, you'll replace it with actuall db calls.

```
// menuitems is cached here in this module. You can make an initial load from db instead.
var menuitems = [];
// getting them is simple, always just get the current array. We'll use that.
var getMenuItems = function() {
    return menuitems;
}

// this executes when we have already inserted - calls the callback
var addMenuItemHandler = function(newItem, callback) {
    // validate that it's not empty or that it does not match any of the existing ones
    menuitems.push(newItem);
    // remember, push item to local array only after it's added to db without errors
    callback();
}
// this one accepts a request to add a new menuitem
var addMenuItem = function(req, res) {
    var newItem = req.query.newitem;

    // it will do db insert, or setTimeout in my case
    setTimeout(function(newItem){
        // we also close our request in a callback
        addMenuItemHandler(newItem, function(){
            res.end('Added.');
        });

    }, 2000);
};

module.exports = {
    addMenuItem: addMenuItem,
    getMenuItems: getMenuItems
}
```

So now you have a module **menuhandler.js**. Let's construct it and use it in our app.

```
var menuHandler = require('./menuhandler');
var app = express();
// config, insert middleware etc here

// first, capture your static routes - the ones before the dynamic ones.
app.get('/addmenuitem', menuHandler.addMenuItem);
app.get('/someotherstaticroute', function(req, res) {
    var menu = menuHandler.getMenuItems();
    res.render('someview', {menu: menu});
});


// now capture everything in your menus.
app.get('/:routename', function(req, res){
    // get current items and check if requested route is in there.

    var menuitems = menuHandler.getMenuItems();
    if(menuitems.indexOf(req.params.routename) !== -1) {
        res.render('myview', {menu: menuitems});
    } else {
        // if we missed the route, render some default page or whatever.
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // ...
});
```

Now you don't go to db if there were no new updates (since menuitems array is always up to date) so your initial view is rendered faster (for that 1 db call, anyway).

**Edit**: oh, I just now saw your Model.js. The problem there is that `this` refers to the object you have returned:

```
{
    setDB: function(db) {
        this.db = db;
    },
    getlist: function(callback, query) {
        this.db.find(query || {}, function (err, doc) { callback(doc) });
    }
}
```

So, no db by default. And since you attach something to the `app` in the initial pageload, you do get something.

But in your current update function, you attach stuff to the new app (`reqApp = req.app`), so now you're not talking to the original app, but another instance of it. And I think that your subsequent requests (after the update) get the scope all mixed up so lose the touch with the actual latest data.

Comment: This was a great example of code to get me off in the right direction and well organized.  I have learned a new trick today.  Thank you, Zlatko.

Comment: Your comment is much better driver to answer peoples' questions here then the reputation points :)

Answer (score 3):

In your code when you start your server it reads from the menu db and creates your routes. When your menu changes, you do not re-read from db again.

I suggest you do something like the following

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    //read from your menu db and do the the route management yourself
});
```

Comment: Yeah this seems like a perfectly viable way to go about this.  I had considered this strategy as an option but it seems to me that one should be able to add and remove from routes while the Express app is running as opposed to a catchall then figure it out route.  This is ultimately what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I think this could be vaiable way of resolving it.